# Kendo UI Datepicker disable typing

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I want users to be able to change a Kendo UI Datepicker value only through its button and selecting the date from the pop-up. How can I prevent users from typing in the Datepicker textbox? Can I disable the textbox without disabling the whole control?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

On your input element add this attribute and value...

```
onkeydown="return false;"
```

This will disable typed input and still allow using the calendar control input.

Comment: only solution that I found to be working well with angularjs integration... Thanks

Comment: On web its working fine but in mobile it's not working. I am using phonegap build for my app.

Comment: Working fine! but copy-paste is still available.

Comment: This was an answer from 2013.  It is possible that the datepicker has changed, and/or browsers have changed since then.  ;)

Comment: sebu, are you developing old school JS, or are you using ReactJS or Angular framework?

Comment: The problem with this is that you can still right-click and paste a value.

Answer (score 19):

Use the control as below-

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
    .Name("FromDate")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { onkeydown = "javascript:return false;" })
)
```

It will disable keyboard typing. Same way other conditions also can be handled.

Comment: This works well although the syntax should be: .HtmlAttributes(new { onkeydown = "javascript:return false;" })

Answer (score 6):

Find your input element, and disable it

```
$('#datepicker').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

( tried it on the kendo demo website  http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datepicker/index.html )

Comment: this does work but when the input has a data-bind="disabled: XXX" then it won't work for some reason

Comment: I had the same issue, and was able to make it work when using a `data-bind="disabled: XXX"` by binding to the viewmodel's change event, and in that bound function setting the attribute to disabled whenever the viewmodel's data changes.

Comment: this disabled the entire date picker, you can't pick, add, write, etc, any date by any ways, not a solution at all

Answer (score 6):

you can do it by two ways

```
  //disable kendo ui  datapicker click event
    $(".k-datepicker input").bind('click dblclick',function () {
         return false;
    });

    //make it readonly
   $(".k-datepicker input").prop("readonly", true);
```

Comment: I think the first option won't prevent the user from reaching the control by pressing TAB.

Answer (score 4):

If you want prevent user to typing date in date picker and only select date from pop-up try this code

```
$(".k-datepicker").find('span').find('input').attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the date and time picker widget should have the option to force input only with UI and not by keyboard... Otherwise it's a recipe for a real DateTime "formating" nightmare !
I am quite surprised that the framework doesn't provide anything for this obvious use case.

I had the same need and got it to work using the following logic:

```
$("#date").kendoDatePicker({
    format: "dd MMMM yyyy"
});
$("#date").attr("readonly","readonly");
```

That way the user cannot enter a value by keyboard and can only input a well formated date using the dropdown date selection window.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the widget does not restrict user while typing in the input. The reason for this behavior is explained here:
[Why widget does not restrict typing](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/datepicker/overview#validation)

Along with all other solutions shared in this thread, the one can create a custom Masked DatePicker, which will restrict the user to a specific date format. Check this how-to demo for more details:

[Create Date Masking](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/datepicker/how-to/date-masking-using-maskedtextbox)

**Note that this is not supported by Kendo UI as a built-in feature, hence you will need to use it on your own risk. The good news is that it works pretty good without known side effects.

Answer (score 0):

```
.HtmlAttributes(new { onkeydown="return false" })
```

Comment: .HtmlAttributes(new { @onkeydown="return false;" }) is working for my in net core. Not a nice solution though

Answer (score 0):

Justin's answer works, but it doesn't prevent a right mouse-click from pasting an incorrect value. You could use the `oncontextmenu` to prevent a right mouse-click

```
oncontextmenu="return false;"
```

This would also prevent the number in the calendar from being copied though.

Answer (score 0):

for tagHelpers just use following

```
output.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "javascript:return false;");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it on HTML level using **onkeydown="return false;"**

```
<input id="datePickerPastId" onkeydown="return false;" title="datepicker" style="width: 13%" class="mr-3" disabled />
```

The **GlobalEventHandlers.onkeydown** is supported by all browsers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Above were close, but if you need to disable paste as well, you'll need to do:

```
onkeydown="return false;" onpaste="return false;"
```