# Kendo UI Datepicker disable typing with using Validator

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker, kendo-validator

I am trying to stop users from typing in a Kendo UI Datepicker with only being able to select value through its button and selecting the date from the pop-up along with still using Kendo UI Validator.

I have tried the answers from: [Kendo UI Datepicker disable typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435861/kendo-ui-datepicker-disable-typing/17441915#17441915)

It does prevent users from typing but the Validator doesn't run on any readonly or disabled fields.

Kendo Dojo with a quick example. 
https://dojo.telerik.com/OJupeNuX

How can I stop users from typing while still validation in place?

Comment: Out of curiosity: What for do you need validation if the user cannot enter invalid entries?

Comment: Require the user to select a date and that the date is not in the future

Comment: You mean like a max value, as with https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker/configuration/max?