# Kendo UI for Angular: Kendo UI Datepicker disable typing/ only textbox section

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-datepicker

I am trying to implement a Kendo UI Datepicker. Date value should be changed only through its button and selecting the date from the pop-up. How can I prevent users from typing in the Datepicker textbox? Can I disable the textbox without disabling the whole control?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kendo UI Datepicker disable typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435861/kendo-ui-datepicker-disable-typing)

Comment: @Giannis, that is for jQuery, How can we implement in Angular?

Comment: Just use it the same way: <kendo-datepicker [value]="value" onkeydown="return false;"></kendo-datepicker>

Comment: I tried but not working. I can able to change textbox value. I want to disable textbox

Comment: Please take a look here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzcsdw?file=app/app.component.ts Is that what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: keyUp & keyDown shoud not work. Totally textbox should be disabled. Date must selected through pop-up using icon.

Comment: Did you visit the link? I am not sure I can understand the desired functionality. Please check your question once again. You asked about preventing the users from typing in the Datepicker control and letting them change date value only through the button. Is that right? Please check the stackblitz I provided and also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: My question was clear. I want to disable only textbox field. I tried **[disabled]="true"** property but it is disabling both icon and textbox.

Comment: So, what's the problem now? Did you check the code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzcsdw?file=app/app.component.ts? The user can select a date through the button, but cannot type a date. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah you are right but, we can change date through up/down arrow buttons and mousewheel. I want to disable them.

Comment: Alright! So, if you inspect the Datepicker element in your console, you will find out that it is actually a <kendo-dateinput> element (what you call the Datepicker textbox) with a <span> element (what you call the Datepicker button). All you need then is to disable the <kendo-dateinput>. If I am not that wrong, I think you have to apply either disabled attribute or 'k-state-disabled' class to the <kendo-dateinput>.

Comment: Yeah I tried with disabled attribute but it is disabling both textbox and date picker button.

Comment: Of course it does. You have to apply the disabled attribute to the <kendo-dateinput> and NOT the entire <kendo-datepicker> element. I am modifying my demo and will answer your question.

Comment: I have modified the demo. Did you check it?

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in my comments, you can prevent users from typing in the `Datepicker` textbox just using `onkeydown="return false;"`. In that case, the user will still be able to use the mouse and/or the arrows.

If you actually want to disable the `Datepicker` textbox 'part' of the control, you have to do it programmatically as the **[disabled]="true"** property will disable the entire control.

The key points are the following:

**html**

```
<kendo-datepicker #datepicker [value]="value"></kendo-datepicker>
```

**ts**

```
this.datepickerRef.element.nativeElement.children[0].children[0].setAttribute('disabled', true);
```

I have prepared a demo. Please take a look here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzcsdw?file=app/app.component.ts and let me know if this is the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a couple of years late on this, but there's a directive you can use for this, `readOnlyInput`:

`<kendo-datepicker [readOnlyInput]="true" [value]="value">`

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/readonly-state/